# How to mock redis in django using django-redis and mockredis

Tags: python, django, redis, django-rest-framework, mocking

Redis is configured as following in django settings:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'CLIENT_CLASS': 'django_redis.client.DefaultClient',
        }
    }
}

CACHE_TTL = 3600
```

I have the following view which uses redis cache:

```
from django.core.cache import cache

class TestView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = TestSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            data = serializer.data
            # save new data to cache
            cache.set(data['title'], data, timeout=CACHE_TTL)
            return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and I have this test that uses the view above and uses cache:

```
class MyTest(APITestCase):
    @patch('redis.StrictRedis', mock_strict_redis_client)
    def test_create(self):
        url = reverse('test-list')
        data = {'title': '77test'}
        response = self.client.post(url, data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        self.assertEqual(IP.objects.count(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(IP.objects.get().title, '77test')
```

The problem is that it uses real redis cache instead of using mocked one. 
I'm looking through http://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/#_testing_with_django_redis and https://github.com/locationlabs/mockredis and can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: In general i would advise against using a mock (it's actually a fake) redis, because it will always be incomplete in subtle ways.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [django-fakeredis](https://pypi.org/project/django-fakeredis/) in django to mock `djagno-redis` easily.

In your case:

```
from django_fakeredis.fakeredis import FakeRedis
....
@FakeRedis("yourview.cache"):
def test_create(self)
    ....
```

If you use get_redis_connection, you can:

```
from django_fakeredis.fakeredis import FakeRedis
@FakeRedis("yourpath.get_redis_connection")
def test_foo():
    ...
```

Comment: Just used this library today and I can confirm it is very easy to use with my DRF backend. By the way, I was the first to star this repository :). If @michael is the maintainer, I would like to say "keep up the good work!"